# define function for consecutive row pairs

Tags: r, rows

I am running a function `cor.matrix` that calculated the correlation between rows in a matrix. The rows you want to correlate is defined by `style=`.
Please see more details here: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rsgcc/docs/cor.matrix

Two examples of the function:

Calcuate correlation on the pairs between the 1st, 2nd and 3rd row in the Matrix "x":

```
 cor.matrix(x, cpus = 1, 
              cormethod = "GCC", style = "pairs.between", 
              var1.id = c(1:3), var2.id = c(1:3),
              pernum = 2000, sigmethod = "two.sided", 
              output = "matrix")
```

calcuate correlation on the adjacent rows ((G1,G2), (G2,G3), (G3,G4),...) in the GEMatrix "x".

```
cor.matrix(x, cpus = 1, 
              cormethod = "GCC", style = "adjacent.pairs", 
              pernum = 2000, sigmethod = "two.sided", 
              output = "matrix")
```

However, I want to calculate the correlation between row 1 and 2, row 3 and 4, row 5 and 6 and so on, until the end of the matrix. . 
Do i need to write some kind of loop to do this or could I use some `rep` command?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this won't look excessively "loopy" although it really is one:

```
 sapply(seq(1, nrow(x)-1, by=2), function(n) cor( x[n,], x[n+1,] ) )
```

But maybe you wanted the `cor.matrix` methods to be employed and looking at the help page makes me think your request could easily be satisfied:

```
var1.id
    a numeric vector specifying the row numbers of genes.
var2.id
    a numeric vector specifying the row numbers of genes. Suppose the var1.id and var2.id 
    are respectively c(1,2) and c(3,6), then the the correlation of gene pairs (G1,G3) and 
   (G2,G6) will be calcuated. For styles of "pairs.between" and "one.pair", this parameter 
   MUST be pre-defined. For the other styles, this parameter can be automatically defined 
   by the program itself.
```

So perhaps just this:

```
cor.matrix(x, cpus = 1, 
              cormethod = "GCC", style = "pairs.between", 
              var1.id = seq(1, nrow(x)-1, by=2), var2.id = seq(2, nrow(x), by=2),
              pernum = 2000, sigmethod = "two.sided", 
              output = "matrix")
```

I get the same error as in the comment below after failing to install the full package with its messy GUI trappings, but getting success in sourcing the rsgcc.R and loading the rnaseq.rda files from the package source. I don't understand why the validity test is as it is (and I think it's a bug), but this code succeeds:

```
 cor.matrix(x, cpus = 1, 
               cormethod = "GCC", style = "adjacent.pairs", 
     #var1.id = seq(1, nrow(x)-1, by=2), var2.id = seq(2, nrow(x), by=2),
     #  Same results with and without that line
               pernum = 2000, sigmethod = "two.sided", 
               output = "matrix")
$corMatrix
              GRMZM2G164785 GRMZM2G070322 AC199961.4_FG001
GRMZM2G162702    -0.8875649     0.0000000        0.0000000
GRMZM2G164785     0.0000000    -0.6789225        0.0000000
GRMZM2G070322     0.0000000     0.0000000        0.5846958

$pvalueMatrix
              GRMZM2G164785 GRMZM2G070322 AC199961.4_FG001
GRMZM2G162702         0.029            NA               NA
GRMZM2G164785            NA         0.147               NA
GRMZM2G070322            NA            NA            0.257
```

I understand it not be exactly what you wanted. I also don't think it is terminologically accurate to call this "correlation".

Comment: > cor.matrix(mat, cpus = 1,
+ cormethod = "GCC", style = "pairs.between",
+ var1.id = seq(1, nrow(mat)-1, by=2), var2.id = seq(2, nrow(mat), by=2),
+ pernum = 2000, sigmethod = "two.sided",
+ output = "matrix")
Error in cor.matrix(mat, cpus = 1, cormethod = "GCC", style = "pairs.between",  : 
  Error: var1.id should be the same with var2.id for the pairs.between style

Comment: I think your latest example compares 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 etc. That is very cpu-demanding when I have a matrix of 2000 rows. My matrix is orginazed so that I want to compare 1-2, 3-4, 4-5 etc...Thanks anyway!

Comment: As I thought I said.... there appears to be a bug. The function does not behave in the manner documented. Not my fault.

Comment: Sorry, will write the maintaner.